# How to start "unbound" at booting

Tags: dns, network-programming

I have set up two DNS cash server, unbound, in ubuntu with the same setting file.
In a desktop PC, unbound works fine from booting PC.
However in a laptop PC, it does not work until I restart unbound.
I write down how I tested my laptop PC below.
If someone finds how to fix it to let unbound work fine just after booting PC without restarting unbound.
Thank you very much.

Test:

On booting PC,

```
$ ping name.domain.com
ping: unknown host name.domain.com
```

I check processes by

```
$ ps -ax | grep unbound
3399 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto unbound
```

And I checked address/port unbound uses by

```
$ sudo ss -lntp | grep unbound
# no results
```

Because I could not get address/port, I try to start unbound by

```
$ sudo service unbound start
```

However there is no difference.

```
$ ping name.domain.com
ping: unknown host name.domain.com
$ ps -ax | grep unbound
3464 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto unbound
$ sudo ss -lntp | grep unbound
# no results
```

I stop and restart unbound. Later everything seems to be fine.

```
$ sudo service unbound stop
$ sudo service unbound start
$ ping name.domain.com
PING name.domain.com (192.168.x.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from name.domain.com (192.168.x.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
$ ps -ax | grep unbound
3564 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/unbound
3652 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto unbound
$ sudo ss -lntp | grep unbound
LISTEN     0      128    192.168.2.100:53                       *:*
users:(("unbound",pid=3564,fd=6))
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:53                       *:*
users:(("unbound",pid=3564,fd=4))
LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:8953                     *:*
users:(("unbound",pid=3564,fd=8))
LISTEN     0      128        ::1:8953                    :::*
users:(("unbound",pid=3564,fd=7))
```

If someone finds what is wrong or thinks of solution or suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your system date is correct ?